# Is it possible to use square bracket notion in class methods?

Tags: javascript, dexie

I am trying to automate running some queries with [dexiejs](https://dexie.org/) but i can get them to work when i create a JavaScript function.

The queries simply don't run...

if i want to `update` i get:

> Promise.js:840 Unhandled rejection: TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined

And the rest of my functionalities i.e `delete` follow the same path

i wrote a simple [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xaander1/1yd0v9uz/54/) to demostrate my problem

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
      <!-- Include Dexie -->
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/dexie@latest/dist/dexie.js"></script>

      <script>
      var db = new Dexie("MyFriendDB");
db.version(1).stores({
    friends: '++id,name,age'
});
db.friends.put({
        name: 'Camilla',
        age: 25 })
    .then(()=>{
    test(db,'friends' )
    });


function test(db,database_name){
//original : db.database_name.delete(1)
db[database_name[delete(1)]] //doesnt run
db.database_name.update(1, {name:"Alex"}).then(()=>{
console.log('success'); //also doesnt run
})
.catch(err=>{console.log(err)});
}
 db.friends.each(result=>{
console.log(result)
})


      </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Should it be `db[database_name].delete(1)`.

Comment: @Bibberty that worked... i have been typing it all wrong. You should probably write that as an answer. The code is asynchronous so you cant see the change physically i verified in the browser application storage it actually worked.

Comment: Just happy it worked for you. Happy coding :)

Comment: alright thanks hope i finish it all tonight